# What do you call a matrix with these properties?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

What do you call a matrix, when multiplied from left and right by vectors $x$ and $v$, then it produces the same result as multiplying it from left and right with $v$ and $x$ respectively.
Basically:
$$
vAx= xAv
$$
With transposes put correctly so that dimensions work out nicely. Also, what does it require for a matrix to satisfy this?
Additionally, what are the geometric consequences of matrix having such properties?

Comment: $\newcommand{\e}{\mathbf{e}}$This happens if and only if $A$ is a symmetric matrix. Can you show this? As a hint: what is $\e_i^T A\e_j$, where $\e_k$ is the $k$-th standard basis vector?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Any formal name for this property of matrices?
Answering your question: A_ij. But this is true for all matrices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\{e_j\}_{j=1}^n$ be the standard basis:$(e_j)_i=\delta_{ji}$ for $i=1,..,n$ and then see that for any matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$
$$a_{ij}=e_iAe_j$$
and thus $A$ is symmetric iff $e_iAe_j=e_jAe_i$ and this is equivalent to
$$vAx=xAv$$
for arbitrary $v,x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ by the basis-property of $\{e_j\}$ and linearity of matrix-multiplication.

Comment: Can I define symmetric matrices as the ones that have this property? Any name for it?

Comment: They are called symmetric because this property is equivalent to $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$ as shown above (and that was the hint of @Minus-One Twelfth), thats the formal name for it.